# How to include an external plugin in my own OSGI Eclipse bundle?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, tycho

I have my own Eclipse platform build by using Tycho.

And i want to include some plugins automatically in it.

So that i can use e.g subclipse without installing it manually.

Whats the possibilities to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the needed plugins / features to your target platform. Then you can define your packaging to include them by default.